# $regex not working with URI in aggregation mongodb

Tags: regex, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-atlas

1. i am using mongoDB atlas as a cloud database
2. using aggregate for search result from mongoDB
3. i am not able to use regex with URI under $match operator, so how can we use for same

   ```
   $match:{
      "connection_profile.details.uri": {
         "$regex": "phacxvod.zvigcrton.org/asp/nhmbhrod",
         "$options": "i"
      }
   }
   ```
4. so my original URI is **https://phacxvod.zvigcrton.org/asp/nhmbhrod/?cmd=start**, i want to pass regex for that
5. what i want is regex have to ignore http protocol and query parameter from the URI, so if i search with **[www.phacxvod.zvigcrton.org](http://www.phacxvod.zvigcrton.org)** then also it give the response

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find `www.phacxvod.zvigcrton.org`, you need to remove the `/asp/nhmbhrod` from your regex:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "connection_profile.details.uri": {
        $regex: "phacxvod.zvigcrton.org",
        $options: "i"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/UBL0pKNC483)

Comment: this way regex working fine, but i need to add regex which ignore http protocol and query parameters from the URI, so how can i use that ?

Comment: This is ignoring `http` protocol and query parameters

Comment: but if i pass any extra character then it wont work, like if i search with **www.** then it wont give result, i have tried in your playground

Comment: Please check [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/UBL0pKNC483)

Comment: ok, so my question is what if we are passing **www** in query but in actual URI we don't have www then, query did not give result

Comment: i want that query has to work like, %LIKE% query

Comment: It is similar to %LIKE% query. This will find you all documents where the value of this field contains: `phacxvod.zvigcrton.org` somewhere in the string

Comment: No need to pass `www` into the regex, if you do, you will only get documents their value contains `www`.